# Running a suite of pytest tests on multiple objects

Tags: pytest

As a small part of a much larger set of tests, I have a suite of test functions I want to run on each of a list of of objects. Basically, I have a set of plugins, and a set of "plugin tests".

Naively, I can just make a list of test functions that take a plugin argument, and a list of plugins, and have a test where I call all of the former on all of the latter. But ideally, each test/plugin combo would appear as an individual test in the results.

Is there already a nicer/standardized way of doing something like this in pytest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out pytest's documentation on parametrization (https://pytest.org/latest/parametrize.html).

It's a mechanism for running the same test a number of times with different parameters -- it sounds like just what you want. It generates tests that run individually, and they have nice output and reporting.

Comment: @MattChaput: Since this answers your question, you should click on the green checkbox below the answer score on the left.  That will "accept" the answer, which is useful to others (and gives you more StackOverflow rep).